# UILabel will not show up on UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

For some reason, UILabels do not show up when building the project on simulator (and no errors are reported by Xcode).

------- This is the code -------

```
import UIKit

class Cursos_PUC: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var Curso_1: UILabel!


}

class Cursos_PUC_TableView: UITableViewController {

    var cursos = ["Arquitetura", "Culinária", "Ciência da Computação"]

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath) as! Cursos_PUC


        let nomeCursos = cursos[indexPath.row]
        cell.Curso_1?.text = nomeCursos

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the label outlet actually connected to the label?

Comment: FYI - `cell.Curso_1?.text` should be `cell.Curso_1.text`. The use of `?` negates the point of the label being declared as implicitly unwrapped.

Comment: You are using a storyboard - which means you are likely trying to make `Cursos_PUC` the `Custom Class` of the cell you hopefully defined there. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using storyboard or Code??
if using storyboard then i think your label outlet is not connected to the label.if not then you must register your class to Table view cell